# SQL Server TDE with Keyvault - how often does it need to contact keyvault?

Tags: sql-server, azure, transparent-data-encryption

I have set up two SQL server VMs in Azure with Availabilitiy groups and transparent data encryption with the key residing in keyvault. I thought that the SQL server would only have to reach out to keyvault to get the key on startup / service restarts, but it seems to reach out with an "unwrap" request every 15 min or so, which seems weird to me. How often does the SQL server connector for keyvault actually have to contact the keyvault and why does it do it? Is it something that could trigger it to happen?

Appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that the SQL server would only have to reach out to keyvault to get the key on startup / service restarts, but it seems to reach out with an "unwrap" request every 15 min or so, which seems weird to me.

What would happen if someone revoked the key, removed the key, generated a new version of the key? Should SQL just keep working with a revoked key? What if someone removed access to the key for that principal?

It's analogous as to when certificate CRLs or other similar security items are checked.

> How often does the SQL server connector for keyvault actually have to contact the keyvault and why does it do it? Is it something that could trigger it to happen?

There are various items which could cause communications to ensue, [one example would be when moving to a new VLF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/database-accessibility-issues-high-volume-customer-workloads). There are times, depending on how the database has been configured and architected, that the number of hits to keyvault seems excessive and I would agree, though there are configuration changes, such as not having small VLFs, or using TF 15025.

There is no public exhaustive list and there's nothing to say it won't change per CU or Major Version.